# How do I wire a permanent magnet synchronous motor?

Tags: motor, wiring

I salvaged this motor from a washing machine with a view to using it to power a bench sander in my workshop.

There are three wires red,white and blue in addition to the green/yellow ground wire.

Given that the motor operated with variable speed and forward/reverse when in the washing machine, would I need to acquire a VFD or could I just connect it to mains through a breaker and on/off switch?

[image]

Comment: there should be associated electronics in the washing machine

Comment: Washing machine is long gone I'm afraid.

Comment: It says what it is right on the nameplate it's likely an AC motor

Comment: @Donal  I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqvNm.png) discussion in one paper on PMS. Skim it and use terms there to help search out more information. I'm unfamiliar with these. So I can't add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... or could I just connect it to mains through a breaker and on/off switch?

Nope.  Sorry.

If it were an induction motor then there would be a slight chance you could get it to run with a separate start capacitor, although there's a much better chance that it'd overheat or it would never generate enough power.

Unless the label is lying to you, however, it's a permanent magnet motor.  That means that even if you had 3-phase power to apply to it, it would just buzz and then overheat.  The *reason* that synchronous motors are called that is because the applied voltage needs to be in phase with the physical position of the shaft, plus or minus a few tens of degrees.

> Given that the motor operated with variable speed and forward/reverse when in the washing machine, would I need to acquire a VFD ... ?

You need to use a driver that's specifically designed for that, or a similar motor.  Basically, that's a giant version of the brushless motors that are found in today's radio control planes and drones.  It needs an electronic speed control that is designed for that type of motor.

*Usually* if you buy a box that calls itself a "VFD" it'll be specifically designed for an induction motor -- while the electronics in a VFD would be perfectly suited for driving a motor like that, the software that determines how to drive the motor given how it's acting would be incorrect, and would probably just get confused and shut the whole thing down.

Comment: Some/many VFDs can do various categories of synchronous motor if set up for them. The 1133Hz is going to be an issue though - most industrial drives don't go above 400-650Hz IIRC.

Comment: That's news to me -- but it's _good_ news.

Comment: I want to purchase a VFD for this motor. So, Would I need a VFD which can deliver 3 phases or would single phase suffice for this motor. Also, I would not need anywhere near 17000 rpm for my application. So, If I was to the frequency range 400-650Hz would that not just result in a corresponding reduction in RPM ?